# Java 8 - how to get multiple attributes of an object from a List?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of locations returned by Google places API and decided to find a Place with a lowest price.

Here is how I implemented it with Java 8:

```
BigDecimal lowestPrice = places.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Place::getPrice, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

It returns me the lowest price but it'll be great to get a name of the Place as well (it has a `name` attribute).

How can I also return a `name` of the place with a lowest price?

Comment: Do you want to return both the name and the price?

Comment: @GBlodgett I want to use the name an price values later so yes I need both.

Comment: Try `places.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Place::getPrice)).get();`

Comment: @HadiJ OP is comparing by the count not price.

Comment: OP said _... find a Place with a lowest price_

Comment: @HadiJ Right, cool since it's ambiguous what the OP is after I'll include both solutions then :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it's really unclear what you want as at first, you seem to say that

> I have a list of locations returned by Google places API and decided
>   **to find a Place with a lowest price**.

then at the bottom of your description, you say that:

> **It returns me the lowest price but it'll be great to get a name of the
>   Place as well** (it has a name attribute).

as if the latter seems to be what you want?

Nevertheless, here are both solutions:

if you want to find the min value by the count after grouping for whatever reason that may be... then you could do something along the lines of:

```
 places.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Place::getPrice))
       .entrySet().stream()
       .min(Comparator.comparingInt((Map.Entry<Integer, List<Place>> e) -> e.getValue().size()))
       .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.get(0)));
```

note that above i've used `Integer` as the entry key, feel free to change this to the appropriate type if it's not an `Integer`.

---

Otherwise, if you're simply after the object with the lowest price then you can do:

```
places.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(Place::getPrice));
```

or:

```
Collections.min(places, Comparator.comparingInt(Place::getPrice));
```

There's no need for grouping and all the stuff going on.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you return the whole `Place` object ?

`places.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Place::getPrice)).get()`

Comment: Good solution. You should rather return an Optional. `.get()` can make an exception if the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should find the `Place` with the lowest price, not the lowest price and `Place` that propose it:

```
places.stream()
      .min(Comparators.comparing(Place::getPrice)) // compare by Price. Should use a second criteria for Place with same Price
      ; // return Optional<Place>
```

If you really need to get the count, you can still do it:

```
  BigDecimal lowestPrice = places.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Place::getPrice, toList()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) // Optional<Map.Entry<BigDecimal, List<Place>>
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            // places = List<Place>, you can use size()
            .ifPresent(places -> places.forEach(System.out::println));
```